# Django and Facebook like session reading

Tags: django, cookies

I want my webapp to let users include a javascript file to their websites and by connecting these website domains to their username of my webapp at my user panel, I want to receive and deliver data on page loads of their sites.

For this I need to read cookie so that my javascript understands that they are logged in to my webapp and by understanding their username via their session, I can let them use the javascript file they include from my server.

How can I achieve this ?